# asp.net checkbox style of treeview

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, styles, treeview

```
-Some1
   -Some2
     -Some3
       -Some4
```

I want to change the background color of checkbox of all parent nodes of last child node on event checked changed. When I checked of Some4 checkbox, Some1's,Some2's and Some3's background of checkbox change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parents() function in Jquery.